# is Admin Panel is a module like others in magento?

Tags: adminhtml

We can see that adminhtml is in `core` codepool like any other core modules.

So is it possible to disable this module like others?

But there is no options at:

```
system > configuration > advanced > Disable Modules Output
```

and also no xml file in app/etc/modules.

Answer (score 1):

Adminhtml module's definition is present in **`Mage_All.xml`** file under **app/etc/modules**.

But to disable it, you will need to remove dependencies of many other modules on it.

Some dependent modules are:

- AdminNotification
- Captcha
- Persistent
  etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think entire admin panel is a module.

As when you make these code `<active>false</active>` under **Mage_All.xml**  it goes down like all other modules in magento

```
<Mage_Admin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
               <Mage_Core/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Admin>
```